# Bug with new navigation- tag info still showing after changing tabs

Tags: bug, new-nav

### Bug

#### Step 1: Normal home tab

[image]

#### Step 2: After clicking on [javascript]

[image]

#### Step 3: Clicking back to home tab, the javascript tag info is still showing.

[image]